# lxml.html does not find body tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I use lxml.html to parse various html pages. Now i recognised that at least for some pages it doesn't find the body tag despite it is present and beautiful soup finds it (even though it uses lxml as parser).

example page: https://plus.google.com/ (what remains of it)

```
import lxml.html
import bs4

html_string = """
    ... source code of https://plus.google.com/ (manually copied) ...
"""

# lxml fails (body is None)
body = lxml.html.fromstring(html_string).find('body')

# Beautiful soup using lxml parser succeeds
body = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'lxml').find('body')
```

any guess about what is happening here is welcome :)

Update:

The problem seems to be related to the encoding.

```
# working version
body = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html_string.encode('unicode-escape')).find('body')
```

Comment: What is your `html_string`?

Comment: @JackFleeting its the content of https://plus.google.com/. I didn't add it as it is quite big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

html_string = requests.get("https://plus.google.com/").content
body = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html_string).find('body')
```

body variable contains body html element

Comment: very interesting. Your code seem to work but it seems to be quite equal to what i did before. The difference seem to be that you use the encoded content while I used the manually copied source code. I will investigate, TY!

Comment: The principal difference I saw was that <body> html tag and it's content are generated from the execution of various javascripts

Comment: the body tag must be hard coded otherwise neither of our codes would work, would it? I took a closer look at the source code and found some hex-encodes characters (e.g. \x3d) It looks like they broke lxml while beautiful soup could handle it.